# Java webstart logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, java-web-start

I am used to adding logging to standalone Java applications and writing the logs to the files using log4j and sl4j. I am moving some applications to a Java web start format and I am not clear on what is the best way to perform the logging to monitor the behaviour of the application. I have thought of two options

1. Write the log to the local machine and provide an option to send the information to the central server under some condition (time, error etc..)
2. Send the output of the log to the server directly

What is best practice?

Comment: I've seen 1. implemented by many programs, but 2. seems bandwidth intensive, intrusive, and overkill.

Comment: Agreed, 2 seems like it's not such a good option. An error with webservices wouldn't be logged in that case. I was wondering if there was any other option but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I've seen 1. implemented by many programs.
2. But 2. seems bandwidth intensive, intrusive, and overkill.

> Agreed, 2 seems like it's not such a good option. An error with webservices wouldn't be logged in that case. I was wondering if there was any other option but I can't think of any.

I was thinking of entirely local sources of problems connecting to the server, but good point.

> What is best practice?

Stick with the majority and use method 1.  Unless you have a marvelous inspiration about how the entire logging/reporting system can be improved, I'd go with "tried and tested".  It is likely to be easiest, best supported by existing frameworks, and should your code falter, has the greatest number of people who have 'been there, done that' to potentially help.

Comment: On option that I generally use is 1 + automatic email sent in case of ERROR/FATAL level (in sl4j) = something unexpected happened (connection/permissioning/missing config file/unhandled exception issues).

Comment: @assylias  Good tweak on the described process.